# Centripetal acceleration of mass $M$ attached to a chain by a light inextensible string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, centripetal-force

A chain of negligible mass has a length of $L$ and a bar of soap of mass $M$ attached to its end by a light inextensible string. It is hung vertically. Then it is turned at the angle $\pi\,\mbox{rad}$ so that it is parallel to the ground and released.

My question is what is the value of the centripetal acceleration when the chain makes an angle $\Sigma$ with the vertical.

However, to my knowledge, centripetal acceleration has the formula
$$
a=v^2 / r
$$

There isn't a mention of any angle here. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does "r" represent in your "a" formula?

Comment: @Bill N r is the radius of the circle i.e the length of the string, which is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think I got a possible answer.

First you need to find the total energy of the system, since the mass starts at a certain height, part of its potential energy will convert to kinetic energy. Its total energy is given by the potential energy at the start (t=t_0), which is E1=mgL. Then, at time t=t_1 the mass will have kinetic and potential energy, then, the total energy will be E2= (mv^2)/2 + mgh', and we can find h'(by trigonometry) using the angle Σ and using the lenght of the chain.

Then, by conservation of energy, you know that E1=E2. Doing some math you solve for v^2 and then use this result in a=v^2/r, where r=L. Doing this, you discover that a=2g(1-cos(Σ))

Comment: Instead of attaching a not-so-readable image with the calculations, please use latex formatting to write the formulae (try it! It works).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I´ll surely use it from now on.

Comment: Where is the "light inextensible string? Where is the initial angle $\pi$ rad?

Comment: @BillN I didn't explicitly represent the π  rad initial angle, I used the information "so that it is parallel to the ground" because it makes more sense (if it was π  rad with respect to the vertical then the chain would be perpendicular to the ground and contradict the"parallel to the ground" statement). But at the top left of the image you can see that the chain is parallel to the ground. The "light inextensible string" part seems that was added to the text just to tell how the soap was attached to the chain.